# How to unfreeze the Hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an object from GraphQL. I need to process one field and then return a Hash.

To do this I initially tried using the `to_h` method. But when I tried to change the value in the field, I got this error:

> FrozenError - can't modify frozen Hash

Then I came up with the idea of using the `dup` method. This method seems to "unfreeze" the original object:

```rb
object.to_h.dup
```

But this doesn't help for "deep" fields. For "deep" fields I had to use the local `dup` method.

Please tell me if there is a more correct solution to the problem?

Comment: I think you need a deep copy/clone or something to copy deep hashes. I don't know the solution but this may help https://rubygems.org/gems/deep_dive

Comment: @muistooshort wow, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails (or ActiveSupport if you want to be pedantic) patches a [`deep_dup`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_dup) method into `Hash` which does a deep copy. So you should be able to say:

```
object.to_h.deep_dup
```

to get a fully mutable version of your Hash.